# how to get uri from bitmap in android 10

Tags: android, bitmap, storage, uri, mediastore

I'm facing a problem in getting URI in android 10 it's working in lower devices but I don't know how to do in android 10. I am uploading a video in the server.

```
 bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
    Uri.parse(path);
```

I also try `ContentValues` but I couldn't understand how to do I am getting some error like can not resolve Q, RELATIVE_PATH, IS_PENDING

```
import android.provider.MediaStore;

 ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
        }
```

can Anyone help me how can I get URI in android 10?

Any Help Would Be Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Set target SDK and compile SDK to 28 for now it will work in android 10

Comment: targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion both are 28 already

Comment: Hope this may help you, https://medium.com/@arkapp/accessing-images-on-android-10-scoped-storage-bbe65160c3f4

Comment: Show what you did with contentValues to obtain an uri.

Comment: It looks as if it would benefit you reading threads tagged mediastore. Its all there.

Comment: "it's working in lower devices" -- it is putting the image where the *user* wants it? Why not use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, and let the *user* decide where the *user's* image should go on the *user's* device (or perhaps in the *user's* chosen cloud storage provider)?

Comment: I am deleting image after uploading so it's not useful to store image in the user's choice path

Comment: @ blackapps with contentValues i am getting error not resolve it's some method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the next snipped to insert new bitmaps into the MediaStore in Andorid 10, and get the Uri. Take into account that this code is for Android 10 only.

The compress format must be related to the mime-type parameter. For example, with a JPEG compress format the mime-type would be "image/jpeg", and so on.
The subFolder parameter is optional.

```
@NonNull
private Uri saveBitmap(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final Bitmap bitmap,
                        @NonNull final Bitmap.CompressFormat format, @NonNull final String mimeType,
                        @NonNull final String displayName, @Nullable final String subFolder) throws IOException
{
    String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(subFolder))
    {
        relativeLocation += File.separator + subFolder;
    }

    final ContentValues  contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);

    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

    OutputStream stream = null;
    Uri uri = null;

    try
    {
        final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);

        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
        }

        stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);

        if (stream == null)
        {
            throw new IOException("Failed to get output stream.");
        }

        if (bitmap.compress(format, 95, stream) == false)
        {
            throw new IOException("Failed to save bitmap.");
        }

        return uri;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (uri != null)
        {
            // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
            resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }

        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: import android.provider.MediaStore; in my code imported this mediaStore is it right?

Comment: MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH is a new field introduced in Android Q. So you need to use this method only with Android Q. Use your old code for older Andorid versions, and this method only for Android Q.

Comment: thank you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303794/10747684 after updating  SDK 29  it's working

Comment: Remember that RELATIVE_PATH only exists in Android Q. If you try to use this code below SDK 29, then it will crash.

Answer (score 1):

First You have to update your sdk to use `MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH`

```
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
```

set this 2 sdk version 29 so you can use `RELATIVE_PATH` and then after try this

```
final ContentValues  contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);
```

you can refer full [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62293259/9172041) by @PerracoLabs.